# In safari browser, refused to display in a frame because it set "X-Frame-Options" to "Deny"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, download, safari

Actually, I tried to download a file inside iFrame using `location.url='download file link'`. it works well in all browsers except safari.

In safari browser, I am facing following issue.

`Refused to display 'mydownlaod url' in a frame because it set "X-Frame-Options" to "Deny".`

Could you please provide your suggestion to download a file inside iframe? Do we have any option to fix this in client side itself?

Comment: You've to change the value of `X-Frame-Options` of the response headers to "sameorigin", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options And no, there's nothing you can do on the client.